# Can rsync be used with x509 certs for authentication? If so, how?

Tags: rsync, x509, rhel-7

I need to use x509 certs to be able to authenticate with a work server.  This is not a problem with ssh and scp sessions but I need to set up cron'd rsync and I don't see how to get rsync to use those certs.

Any suggestions as to how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When rsync is used with SSH, it will call the actual `ssh` command as the transport and will use the exact same configuration as OpenSSH itself would.

This means that any keypairs or certificates specified in `~/.ssh/config` will be used, as will the ones loaded into ssh-agent (as long as your cronjob sets the correct SSH_AUTH_SOCK).

If you've previously used command-line options with 'ssh' or 'scp', I would strongly recommend converting those to ~/.ssh/config parameters... but they can still be specified using `rsync -e`.

Standard OpenSSH does not support X.509 certificates – only raw public keys or the OpenSSH-specific certificate format – but everything still applies to whatever "OpenSSH with X.509" variant you may be using.